# How to list all audio devices that are enabled and present for recording the output audio of the pc?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, ffmpeg, naudio

I want to record with ffmpeg later the entire desktop including audio.
I want to make that it will find for me automatic the recording audio device.

I'm using MMDeviceEnumerator.

all the other ways I tried returned empty list returned 0 audio devices.  I tried with naudio and ffmpeg

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeRecordingIndicator();

            MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            foreach (MMDevice device in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.All))
            {
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\audiodev.txt", true);
                cmbAudioDevices.Items.Add(device.FriendlyName);
                w.WriteLine(device.FriendlyName + " " + device.State);
                w.Close();
            }
        }
```

This is the list of all my audio deviceso n my system.
but they are all not present or disabled. and i have audio on my pc i can hear games videos anything.

so what would i select from this list as audio device for recording the pc output audio?
or maybe i need to find another way to find the right audio device?

```
Front Green In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Center (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Grey In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Side (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Rear Pink In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) NotPresent
Front (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Orange In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Line In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Front Pink In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Line In (Realtek(R) Audio) Unplugged
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio) Unplugged
Subwoofer (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Black In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio) Disabled
Rear Green In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Blue In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Front Green In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Center (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Grey In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Side (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Rear Pink In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) NotPresent
Front (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Orange In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Line In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Front Pink In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Line In (Realtek(R) Audio) Unplugged
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio) Unplugged
Subwoofer (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Black In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio) Disabled
Rear Green In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Blue In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Front Green In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Center (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Grey In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Side (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Rear Pink In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (NVIDIA High Definition Audio) NotPresent
Front (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Orange In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Line In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Front Pink In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Line In (Realtek(R) Audio) Unplugged
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Internal AUX Jack (High Definition Audio Device) NotPresent
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio) Unplugged
Subwoofer (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Black In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio) Disabled
Rear Green In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
Rear Blue In (Realtek(R) Audio) NotPresent
```

this is how i tried with naudio but it didn't working it didn't find anything.:

```
using NAudio.Wave;
...

// Enumerate and list audio input devices
var devices = WaveInEvent.DeviceCount;
for (int deviceId = 0; deviceId < devices; deviceId++)
{
    var deviceInfo = WaveInEvent.GetCapabilities(deviceId);
    Console.WriteLine($"Device ID: {deviceId}, Name: {deviceInfo.ProductName}");
}
```

before that i tried with ffmpeg but also it didn't return anything:

```
public static class FFmpegHelper
    {
        public static string[] GetAudioCaptureDevices()
        {
            string ffmpegPath = @"C:\path\to\ffmpeg.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegPath;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            string output = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            string[] lines = output.Split('\n');
            var devices = lines.Where(line => line.Contains("audio")).Select(line => line.Trim()).ToArray();
            return devices;
        }
    }
```

using it:

```
var audioDevices = FFmpegHelper.GetAudioCaptureDevices();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues within your question. First you will need to re-read your own question and see if it convey your itention. From what I understand you want to find all audio output devices on your system. And you want to record audio output from these output devices. Your ffmpeg should work. However you are doing it strangely.

Why are you looking at StandardError for output? And I don't think you should filter specifically for the word "audio"

Try this

```
using System.Diagnostics;

static string[] GetAudioCaptureDevices()
{
    var process = new Process 
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"D:\temp\ffmpeg.exe",
            Arguments = "-list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    return new string[] {};
}

GetAudioCaptureDevices();
```

which will give you output like this

```
[dshow @ 000002ca4f7c89c0] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 000002ca4f7c89c0]  "Integrated Webcam"
[dshow @ 000002ca4f7c89c0]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_1bcf&pid_28c1&mi_00#6&2d640bac&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 000002ca4f7c89c0] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 000002ca4f7c89c0]  "Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio)"
[dshow @ 000002ca4f7c89c0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{7F236980-BB25-46A8-AC39-5C7F156FD2B7}"
[dshow @ 000002ca4f7c89c0]  "Microphone (Steam Streaming Microphone)"
[dshow @ 000002ca4f7c89c0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{E2C402FA-B9F9-4B04-BCD9-852C8B7C0A72}"
```